# How do I delete the last line of a text file using the echo command in windows?

Tags: windows, echo

How do I delete the last line of a text file using the echo command in windows?

Comment: Can you use a batch file instead?

Answer (score 3):

Echo only has 2 uses:

> ECHO [ON | OFF]
>   ECHO [message]

You can overwrite a file completely using a redirect

```
ECHO Testing > a.txt
```

Or you can append to a file using an append redirect

```
ECHO Testing >> a.txt
```

Or you can write a new line

```
ECHO.
```

But you can't use it to remove the last line

Answer (score 0):

Have a look for a 'tail' command/equivalent (plenty on google depending on OS version).

then

copy oldfile tempfile

tail -1 > oldfile

Regards
Michael.